# make sticky div go left of the viewable part of the container

Tags: css

I have some divs that can get added and as you can see in the example below when there are not enough divs the sticky div starts at the beginning.
I will have a container div that inherits from the parent and I would like my sticky div always show at the right of the viewable part of the container div. Is this possible?

```css
#container {
 
 overflow:scroll;
 display:flex;
 width:100%;
 flex-direction:row;
 max-width:inherit;
 background-color:azure;

}

.item {

 min-width:30px;
 min-height:90px;
 background-color:green;
 border:1px solid white;

}

.sticky{

  background-color:orange;
  position:sticky;
  right:0;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item sticky"></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item sticky"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean: `.sticky { margin-left: auto }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand your issue correctly, the solution seems simple:

- Add `.sticky { margin-left: auto }` to your CSS and the `.sticky` element will be forced to the right margin of its parent element `#container`.

```css
#container {
    overflow: scroll;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: inherit;
    background-color: azure;
}

.item {
    min-width: 30px;
    min-height: 90px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.sticky {
    background-color: orange;
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;

    margin-left: auto; /* Solution */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="item sticky"></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item sticky"></div>
</div>
```